# How to work around implicitly imported units in Delphi packages

Tags: delphi, import, package, delphi-2007

I use GnuGetText to perform localization.  This unit is used all over the place.  So, when I create Package A, GnuGetText is implicitly imported in.  And when I create Package B, GnuGetText is also implicitly imported in.  The problem is that this unit can only appear in one Package.  I do not understand how to "move" the unit into a unique location so that it does not appear in both Packages A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Since `GnuGetText` is being shared by multiple packages, you need to put it into its own package that the other packages can then specify in their `Requires` list.

Comment: Remy: thanks for your help.  I created a new Package for GnuGetText (which is a Unit, not a Component), and put that new Package in the Requires list for Package A.  When I compile Package A, it still implicitly imports GnuGetText, which then causes the problem again.

Comment: It does not need to be a component in order to be put in a package. Standalone units work just as well in packages. If Package A `Requires` your GnuGetText Package then it should not be implicitly importing the `GnuGetText` unit anymore. That is the whole point. `Requires` takes priority. The compiler will look for the `GnuGetText` unit in the `Required` packages first (that is what allows common units to be shared across packages), and only if not found then will it go hunting for `GnuGetText.dcu` or `GnuGetText.pas` to implicitly import.